# Multiple polymorphic associations on the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I have a `Flag` model which is joined to multiple other objects with `FlagInstance` and a polymorphic `flaggable` on that table:

```
table 'flag_instances'
flag_id
flaggable_id
flaggable_type
.....
```

With has many_through I'm able to fetch any flaggable object like `user.flags` which is great.

However I'm trying to flag objects with errors and the notify other objects so I've added

```
table 'flag_instances'
flag_id
flaggable_id
flaggable_type
notifiable_id
notifiable_type
.....
```

The problem is, a `User` can have a flag and can be *notified* of a flag. So `user.flags` isn't specific enough to show me which is a `flag` and which is a notification of a `flag`.

I think I need to change the relationships:

```
user.rb
has_many :flag_instances, as: :flaggable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :flags, through: :flag_instances
has_many :flag_instances, as: :notifiable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :flags, through: :flag_instances
```

But I'm not sure what to change them to. Can someone please suggest a solution?

Note: both flags and notifications of flags can belong to multiple objects, so they  both need to remain polymorphic.

Thanks

Comment: Do flag and notification have to be in same entry? What I mean is when a flag_instances entry is a flag, can it also be notification too at the same time? i.e. single entry has value in all 4: `flaggable_id, flaggable_type, notifiable_id, and notifiable_type` columns?

Comment: Yes, every entry will always have all 4 populated. Occasionally they'll have the same object in them, but usually it'll be different objects (E.G. Flag an AccessToken as expired and Notify a User)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Association for notifiable needs to be changed. In this case user.rb:

```
has_many :flag_instances, as: :flaggable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :flags, through: :flag_instances

has_many :notifiables, as: :notifiable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'FlagInstance'
has_many :notifications, through: :notifiables, class_name: 'Flag'
```

Note: You might also need to provide [`foreign_key`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key) in case Rails association is not able to pick up the key itself.

Answer (score 1):

Each association must have a unique name - otherwise the later definition will just overwrite the former.

Here the third line overwrites the first line:

```
has_many :flag_instances, as: :flaggable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :flags, through: :flag_instances
has_many :flag_instances, as: :notifiable, dependent: :destroy
```

To reference the correct associations we would need to setup the user model as so:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :flag_instances_as_flaggable, 
     as: :flaggable
     class_name: 'FlagInstance'
  has_many :flags_as_flaggable, 
     through: :flag_instances_as_flaggable, 
     source: :flag
  has_many :flag_instances_as_notifiable, 
     as: :notifiable
     class_name: 'FlagInstance'
  has_many :flags_as_notifiable,
     through: :flag_instances_as_notifiable,
     source: :flag
end
```

In your case you might want to use concerns to keep it dry:

```
module Flaggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_many :flag_instances_as_flaggable, 
      as: :flaggable,
      class_name: 'FlagInstance'
    has_many :flags_as_flaggable,
      through: :flag_instances_as_flaggable, 
      source: :flag
  end
end

module Notifiable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_many :flag_instances_as_notifiable, 
      as: :notifiable,
      class_name: 'FlagInstance'
    has_many :flags_as_notifiable,
      through: :flag_instances_as_notifiable,
      source: :flag
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Flaggable
  include Notifiable
end
```

Comment: I believe Suryas answer is correct. But just wondering, in your solution how does active record know to look in a table called flag_instances?

Comment: I actually forgot to add `class_name: 'FlagInstance'` which is needed since the name of the class cannot be derided from the name of the association.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks!

Comment: Its not needed in the `though:` association when you specify `source:` as AR gets the class name from the association that its going though (Flag).

Comment: I would probably do this with a separate Notification model though instead of shoehorning everything into a single class. This lets you create a m-2-m association so that you can keep track of in-app notifications and for example email notifications.

Comment: Thanks Max, that's going to be the natural progression in the future. But for now this fits the use case.